# How can I use global functions in Vue?

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vue-component, global

I have a date formatting function. Now I need to use this method in different components. What's the best practice for this situation? Directive? Filters? Or something different? How can I define this?

```js
dateWithoutTime(date) {
  return date ? date.split("T")[0] : ""
}
```

Comment: Create a mixin and put the function (method) inside it then just include the mixin where you need that function.

Comment: Note that mixins are an anti-pattern and were eliminated in Vue 3, best not to use one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Module

Assuming you're using Vue CLI or an equivalent bundler, the way that is most composable would be to create a module for utility functions like:

*utilities.js*

```js
export const dateWithoutTime = function(date) {
  return date ? date.split("T")[0] : ""
}
```

Then you could import that function wherever you need it:

*SomeComponent.vue*

```js
import { dateWithoutTime } from '@/modules/utilities.js'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    someDate: new Date()
  }),
  methods: {
    someMethod() {
      return dateWithoutTime(this.someDate);
    }
  }
}
```

<sub>Edit: *You could also make it a method to use it directly from the template:*</sub>

```js
methods: {
  dateWithoutTime      // Same as `dateWithoutTime: dateWithoutTime`
}
```

#### Vue.prototype

Another option is to set the function on `Vue.prototype` prior to instantiating your app:

*main.js*

```js
Vue.prototype.$dateWithoutTime = function(date) {
  return date ? date.split("T")[0] : ""
}

new Vue({
...
})
```

Then the function can be used in any component like:

*SomeComponent.vue*

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    someDate: new Date()
  }),
  methods: {
    someMethod() {
      return this.$dateWithoutTime(this.someDate);
    }
  }
}
```